# Can't display unicode

Tags: haskell, unicode, ghc

I have a feeling that this has already been answered somewhere: if so I apologise.

I am trying to use an executable that writes Unicode characters to standard output.  All I get is this error message (hPutChar from Haskell):

```
<stderr>: hPutChar: invalid argument (invalid character)
```

Just to be clear: the executable is not mine, I cannot change what it outputs.

Is there some way to get bash to display these characters?  My bash version is 4.3.30 on Debian Jessie.

Thanks very much.

Comment: What is your locale? BTW bash has nothing to do with this. Editing tags. Just guessing you have ghc. Feel free to correct this.

Comment: Umm - sorry, what do I need to type in to find my locale?

Comment: Try typing `locale` and see if it helps.

Comment: OK - I see lots of "POSIX" strings.  Is there a specific line that would help?

Comment: usually all those are the same (I am from germany so I see lot's of de_DE.UTF-8`) - I thinkg n.m. s question was what's yours?

Comment: All of the strings after the '='s are "POSIX".  LANG and LANGUAGE are blank.

Comment: oh ... that's strange - is this Arch? ... you should set your locale IMO

Comment: Umm - it's Debian.  If it's unusual that probably because it's a [chroot](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/).  What do I need to do to set my locale?

Comment: if you don't see yours with `locale -a` you have to generate it with something like `sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8` - once you have it you can activate it with `update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` then after reboot it should be set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104086/discussion-between-rhubarbandc-and-carsten).

Comment: "it's a chroot" that explains it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your user environment is not set up correctly to handle Unicode. Your locale should be set to `<language>_<territory>.utf-8` or some spelling variation thereof (some systems use UTF8 or utf8). Type `locale -a` to see a list of supported locales. Type

```
 export LANG=<your preferred locale name>
```

and run your progran again. The program should stop complaining. If you don't see correct characters, and you are running X11, type `xterm&` (or whatever terminal emulator you prefer) in the same session, and try again.

If there are no suitable locales, you may need to generate some. [This](http://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment) seem to explain how to do that on Debian.

Comment: I found this link more useful than the one you suggested though: http://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment

Comment: You're right, I have replaced it with your suggested link.